# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION while connecting to SQL Server 2016 from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

The following is the error that shows up when I try connecting to database:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006d21cef5, pid=10392, tid=14036
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x13cef5]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Sathi\workspace\JDBC1\hs_err_pid10392.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Below is my basic code for that:

```
    package com.info.dbconnection;

    import java.sql.*;
    public class DataBaseConnection {

        public static Connection getConnection(){
            Connection con = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                 con = DriverManager
                        .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=SampleDB;integratedSecurity=true;");
                 System.out.println("Connection has been created:: " + con);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return con;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you are running a fairly old version of Java 8 (the most recent version is 1.8.0_144) so you probably should upgrade. You also should verify that you are using the latest version of Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server.

Comment: What is the JDBC driver that you are using here, the version?

Comment: I am using Microsoft's JDBC driver 6.0 for SQL Server. I tried updating JRE latest version but getting the same error.
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000711ef255, pid=2692, tid=0x0000000000001e64
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of sqlserver driver (sqljdbc)

Comment: You should provide some more context for your post to be a good answer, like try to explain what indicates that OP should update the driver. Your answer is as it is now more like a comment